how to fetch data in Vite SSR with React?
i am currently migrating from a vite with react simple app to an SSR one, and while doing so i've countered the fetching data issue (i'm new to SSR) so i was using react query (tenstack query) to fetch data in my simple app, and now when i'm switching to SSR i don't understand how to fetch the data properly !
here is the code of the component :
export default function Component() {
  const { data, isLoading, error } = useGetProductsQuery();

  if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  if (error || data === undefined) {
      return <div>Error occurred, please try again later</div>;
  }

  if (data.length === 0) {
      return <div>No products found</div>;
  }

  return (
//...
        <Products data={data} />
//...
  );
}

so in the server it is rendering the "loading ..."
and then in the client also rendering loading ... and then get the products
but i want to render the products directly from the server and then only hydrate to the client
i tried removing the loading but it only gonna get undefined data, so please help me.
for more info here is the server.js of the SSR vite (the default one) :


import fs from 'node:fs/promises'
import express from 'express'
import { Transform } from 'node:stream'

// Constants
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 5173
const base = process.env.BASE || '/'
const ABORT_DELAY = 10000

// Cached production assets
const templateHtml = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile('./dist/client/index.html', 'utf-8')
  : ''
const ssrManifest = isProduction
  ? await fs.readFile('./dist/client/.vite/ssr-manifest.json', 'utf-8')
  : undefined

// Create http server
const app = express()

// Add Vite or respective production middlewares
let vite
if (!isProduction) {
  const { createServer } = await import('vite')
  vite = await createServer({
    server: { middlewareMode: true },
    appType: 'custom',
    base
  })
  app.use(vite.middlewares)
} else {
  const compression = (await import('compression')).default
  const sirv = (await import('sirv')).default
  app.use(compression())
  app.use(base, sirv('./dist/client', { extensions: [] }))
}

// Serve HTML
app.use('*', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const url = req.originalUrl.replace(base, '')

    let template
    let render
    if (!isProduction) {
      // Always read fresh template in development
      template = await fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8')
      template = await vite.transformIndexHtml(url, template)
      render = (await vite.ssrLoadModule('/src/entry-server.jsx')).render
    } else {
      template = templateHtml
      render = (await import('./dist/server/entry-server.js')).render
    }

    let didError = false

    const { pipe, abort } = render(url, ssrManifest, {
      onShellError() {
        res.status(500)
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        res.send('<h1>Something went wrong</h1>')
      },
      onShellReady() {
        res.status(didError ? 500 : 200)
        res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })

        const transformStream = new Transform({
          transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            res.write(chunk, encoding)
            callback()
          }
        })

        const [htmlStart, htmlEnd] = template.split(`<!--app-html-->`)

        res.write(htmlStart)

        transformStream.on('finish', () => {
          res.end(htmlEnd)
        })

        pipe(transformStream)
      },
      onError(error) {
        didError = true
        console.error(error)
      }
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      abort()
    }, ABORT_DELAY)
  } catch (e) {
    vite?.ssrFixStacktrace(e)
    console.log(e.stack)
    res.status(500).end(e.stack)
  }
})

// Start http server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started at http://localhost:${port}`)
})



